# Problema para sumar dias en intervalos SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

tengo un inconveniente con una consulta en SQL
Creé una query que me trae en formato de 15 minutos las llamadas de un sistema,
el problema es que cuando pongo mas de 1 dia me agrega otra fila.
 por ejemplo si 08:00 a 08:15 hubo 10 llamadas ayer y hoy en ese rango hubo 15 me trae dos filas de 10 y 15 y necesito que me traiga una sola con 25

adjunto el codigo para ver donde puede fallar

```
    DECLARE @fecha_desde datetime = '20200501'
DECLARE @fecha_hasta datetime = '20200515'
DECLARE @cola varchar(255) = '531'


use vondatp

SET NOCOUNT ON;
declare @intervalo int

set @intervalo = 15

    -- crear tabla temporal de resultados
    declare @resultado table    (desde datetime,
                                 hasta datetime,
                                 recibidas int,
                                 atendidas int, 
                                 abandonadas int, 
                                 attmen10 int,
                                 attmen20 int,
                                 attmen40 int,
                                 attplus40 int,
                                 abbmen10 int,
                                 abbmen20 int,
                                 abbmen40 int,
                                 abbplus40 int,
                                 asaprom int,
                                 asamax int,
                                 ahtprom int,
                                 ahtmen10 int,
                                 ahtmen20 int,
                                 ahtmen30 int,
                                 ahtmen60 int,
                                 ahtmen180 int,
                                 ahtplus180 int
                                 )

    declare @fecha_aux datetime
    set @fecha_aux = @fecha_desde



    while @fecha_aux < dateadd(d,1,@fecha_hasta)
    begin
        insert into @resultado (desde, hasta) values (@fecha_aux,DATEADD(minute,@intervalo,@fecha_aux))
        set @fecha_aux = DATEADD(MINUTE,@intervalo,@fecha_aux)
    end --- while

    declare cursor_rangos cursor for
    select desde,hasta from @resultado

    declare @desde_aux datetime
    declare @hasta_aux datetime


    open cursor_rangos
    fetch next from cursor_rangos into @desde_aux, @hasta_aux

    declare @auxaux table       (recibidas_aux int,
                                 atendidas_aux int, 
                                 abandonadas_aux int, 
                                 attmen10_aux int,
                                 attmen20_aux int,
                                 attmen40_aux int,
                                 attplus40_aux int,
                                 abbmen10_aux int,
                                 abbmen20_aux int,
                                 abbmen40_aux int,
                                 abbplus40_aux int,
                                 asaprom_aux int,
                                 asamax_aux int,
                                 ahtprom_aux int,
                                 ahtmen10_aux int,
                                 ahtmen20_aux int,
                                 ahtmen30_aux int,
                                 ahtmen60_aux int,
                                 ahtmen180_aux int,
                                 ahtplus180_aux int
                                 )

    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        begin 
        print '--- desde' + format(@desde_aux,'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm') + ' hasta ' + format(@hasta_aux,'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm')


        insert into @auxaux (recibidas_aux,atendidas_aux,abandonadas_aux,attmen10_aux,attmen20_aux,attmen40_aux,attplus40_aux,abbmen10_aux,abbmen20_aux,abbmen40_aux,abbplus40_aux,asaprom_aux,asamax_aux,ahtprom_aux,ahtmen10_aux,ahtmen20_aux,ahtmen30_aux,ahtmen60_aux,ahtmen180_aux,ahtplus180_aux)
        (select count(*) ,
                sum(case when convduration > 0 then 1 else 0 end),
                sum(case when convduration = 0 and waitduration > 0 then 1 else 0 end),
                sum(case when convduration > 0 and waitduration >= 0 and waitduration < 10 then 1 else 0 end) ,
                sum(case when convduration > 0 and waitduration >= 10 and waitduration < 20 then 1 else 0 end),
                sum(case when convduration > 0 and waitduration >= 20 and  waitduration < 40 then 1 else 0 end),
                sum(case when convduration > 0 and waitduration >= 40 then 1 else 0 end),
                sum(case when convduration = 0 and waitduration > 0  and waitduration < 10 then 1 else 0 end),
                sum(case when convduration = 0 and waitduration >= 10 and waitduration < 20 then 1 else 0 end),
                sum(case when convduration = 0 and waitduration >= 20 and waitduration < 40 then 1 else 0 end),
                sum(case when convduration = 0 and waitduration >= 40 then 1 else 0 end),
                avg(case when ConvDuration > 0 then WaitDuration else null end),
                max(case when ConvDuration > 0 then WaitDuration else null end),
                avg(case when convduration > 0 then convduration else null end),
                sum(case when convduration > 0 and convduration < 10 then 1 else 0 end),
                sum(case when convduration >= 10 and convduration < 20 then 1 else 0 end),
                sum(case when convduration >= 20 and convduration < 30 then 1 else 0 end),
                sum(case when convduration >= 30 and convduration < 60 then 1 else 0 end),
                sum(case when convduration >= 60 and convduration < 180 then 1 else 0 end),
                sum(case when convduration >= 180 then 1 else 0 end)
        from ODCalls
        where calllocaltime between @desde_aux and @hasta_aux
        and CustomerID = 1
        and CallType = 1
        and FirstQueue = @cola)


            update @resultado
            set recibidas = b.recibidas_aux,
                atendidas = b.atendidas_aux,
                abandonadas = b.abandonadas_aux,
                attmen10 = b.attmen10_aux,
                attmen20 = b.attmen20_aux,
                attmen40 = b.attmen40_aux,
                attplus40 = b.attplus40_aux,
                abbmen10 = b.abbmen10_aux,
                abbmen20 = b.abbmen20_aux,
                abbmen40 = b.abbmen40_aux,
                abbplus40 = b.abbplus40_aux,
                asamax = b.asamax_aux,
                asaprom = b.asaprom_aux,
                ahtprom = b.ahtprom_aux,
                ahtmen10 = b.ahtmen10_aux,
                ahtmen20 = b.ahtmen20_aux,
                ahtmen30 = b.ahtmen30_aux,
                ahtmen60 = b.ahtmen60_aux,
                ahtmen180 = b.ahtmen180_aux,
                ahtplus180 = b.ahtplus180_aux
            from @resultado a, @auxaux b
            where desde = @desde_aux

        delete from @auxaux

            fetch next from cursor_rangos into @desde_aux, @hasta_aux
        end --cursor

    close cursor_rangos
    deallocate cursor_rangos

    select  format(desde,'HH:mm') as 'Desde',
            format(hasta,'HH:mm') as 'Hasta',
            recibidas AS 'Recibidas',
            atendidas AS 'Atendidas',
            abandonadas AS 'Abandonadas',
            attmen10 as 'Atendidas lt 10',
            attmen20 as 'Atendidas lt 20',
            attmen40 as 'Atendidas lt 40',
            attplus40 as 'Atendidas gt 40',
            abbmen10 as 'Abandonadas lt 10',
            abbmen20 as 'Abandonadas lt 20',
            abbmen40 as 'Abandonadas lt 40',
            abbplus40 as 'Abandonadas gt 40',
            asaprom as 'ASA Prom',
            asamax as 'ASA Max',
            ahtprom as 'Conversado Prom',
            ahtmen10 as 'Conversado lt 10',
            ahtmen20 as 'Conversado lt 20',
            ahtmen30 as 'Conversado lt 30',
            ahtmen60 as 'Conversado lt 60',
            ahtmen180 as 'Conversado lt 180',
            ahtplus180 as 'Conversado &gt; 180'
    from @resultado
    where recibidas > 0
```

Comment: ¿Ya intentaste hacer un SUM() con los campos que traen las cantidades y el group by por los campos desde y hasta?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que por cada día se repetirá el rango de horas que quieres, solamente debes sumar los datos (o sacar promedio, en algunos casos según los campos que compartiste) y agruparlos por los rangos de hora, algo asi quiza te funcione:

```
select  
format(desde,'HH:mm') as 'Desde',
format(hasta,'HH:mm') as 'Hasta',
sum(recibidas) AS 'Recibidas',
sum(atendidas) AS 'Atendidas',
sum(abandonadas) AS 'Abandonadas',
sum(attmen10) as 'Atendidas lt 10',
sum(attmen20) as 'Atendidas lt 20',
sum(attmen40) as 'Atendidas lt 40',
sum(attplus40) as 'Atendidas gt 40',
sum(abbmen10) as 'Abandonadas lt 10',
sum(abbmen20) as 'Abandonadas lt 20',
sum(abbmen40) as 'Abandonadas lt 40',
sum(abbplus40) as 'Abandonadas gt 40',
avg(asaprom) as 'ASA Prom',
avg(asamax) as 'ASA Max',
avg(ahtprom) as 'Conversado Prom',
sum(ahtmen10) as 'Conversado lt 10',
sum(ahtmen20) as 'Conversado lt 20',
sum(ahtmen30) as 'Conversado lt 30',
sum(ahtmen60) as 'Conversado lt 60',
sum(ahtmen180) as 'Conversado lt 180',
sum(ahtplus180) as 'Conversado &gt; 180'
from @resultado
where recibidas > 0
group by
format(desde,'HH:mm'),
format(hasta,'HH:mm')
```